# How set base dir in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my website with structure of

- mywebsite

  - index.php
  - index_admin.php

By rewriting though .htaccess

```
www.mywebsite.com/home/main --converts--> mywebsite/index.php
www.mywebsite.com/home/admin --converts--> mywebsite/index_admin.php
```

this is working (hosted)

Now I tried it to run on localhost for dev purpose using XAMPP Linux
url

`localhost/mywebsite/index.php` launched but when logined and navigate to url `/home/admin` it become `localhost/home/admin` which does not found. I want it to become `/localhost/mywebsite/home/admin` so that correctly navigate to `index_admin.php` file

Comment: You might want to look into [the front controller pattern](https://webdevetc.com/blog/the-front-controller-design-pattern-in-php/) together with a router. Then you only need to configure the web server to redirect all requests to non existing files/folders to index.php and handle all routes in the application instead. It also makes it much easier to migrate the application to another web server (like nginx that doesn't read htaccess).

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question